# Is it possible to isolate a BGR color gradient with cv2.inRange()?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am writing a program that observes an area on the screen that displays a number between 0 and 100. When the number is 100, it has green text. When the number is 0, it has red text. As the number decreases from 100, it slowly shifts in a gradient from solid green to solid red.

Some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

`100` is `rgb(0, 255, 0)`

`84` is `rgb(73, 255, 0)`,

`65` is `rgb(172, 255, 0)`,

`41` is `rgb(255, 213, 0)`,

`17` is `rgb(255, 88, 0)`

`0` is `rgb(255, 0, 0)`

**Question**

Is it possible to isolate *any/all* colors in this range using `cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)` where `lower` and `upper` are numpy arrays in the form `[B, G, R]`? If there is a suitable range, can you explain why it works?

I have this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("image_of_text.png")

# Generate mask for color range
lower = [0, 0, 0]
upper = [0, 0, 0]
mask = cv2.inRange(image, np.array(lower), np.array(upper))

# Create black mask
h, w = image.shape[:2]
mask_b = np.zeros([h, w, 1], dtype=np.uint8)

# Combine masks
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask_b, mask)
cv2.imshow('result', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I would prefer to avoid HSV ranges as the rest of my program is not well suited for switching color spaces on the fly.

Comment: It might be useful to convert the image to a colourspace like HSV or HSL and then do thresholding on the hue component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved this as I was writing up the question.

From what I can tell, we need to isolate two separate ranges:

GREEN --> `lower` = `rgb(0, 255, 0)`, `upper` = `rgb(255, 255, 0)`

RED   --> `lower` = `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, `upper` = `rgb(255, 255, 0)`

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("image_of_text.png")

upper = [0, 255, 255]  # uppper is same for both

# Green range
lower = [0, 255, 0]
mask_g = cv2.inRange(image, np.array(lower), np.array(upper))

# Red range
lower = [0, 0, 255]
mask_r = cv2.inRange(image, np.array(lower), np.array(upper))

# Create black mask
h, w = image.shape[:2]
mask_b = np.zeros([h, w, 1], dtype=np.uint8)

# Combine masks
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask_b, mask_g)
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask, mask_r)
cv2.imshow('result', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Just from looking at the text colors I listed in the question, I noticed how both middle numbers were close to rgb(255, 255, 0), but since there were two distinct ends to this gradient, I needed to specify two separate lower bounds while they both have the same upper bound.